# Analysis of Differentiable Functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is a function such that $|f(x)− f(y)| ≤ |x−y|^2$ for all $x$ and $y$. Show that $f (x) = C$ for some constant $C$.

Hint: Show that $f$ is differentiable at all points and compute the derivative

I confused as to what I use as the function in order to show that $f$ is differentiable at all points

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: Hint: by squeezing $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ exists and is equal to...

Comment: This is a Holder's continuous function.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $y=x+h$, then you have
$$abs\left( \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right)\le |h|,$$ so that as $h \to 0$ you get that $f$ is differentiable. Maybe now you can use differentiability of $f$ to finish.

Actually once you know it's differentiable, the same inequality above shows the derivative is $0$, so not really more work, just to explain it on your write-up.

Comment: so taking the limits of both sides you end up with f'(x) <= 0. But how does this show the derivative is 0?

Comment: @user72195 -- Don't forget about the absolute value around the left fraction. If $|w(h)|\to 0$ as $h \to 0$ then it follows that $w(h) \to 0$ (for any function $w(h)$ defined at all $h$ in a deleted neighborhood of $0$).

Comment: so since the absolute value cannot be negative, its simplifies from abs(f'(x)) <= 0 to f'(x)=0 ?

Comment: Yes. So you end with $f'(x)=0$ at all $x$ so $f(x)$ must be constant.